# SMBJ & Delphi 10.3.3

Tags: android, delphi

I would like to use smbj in my Delphi applications for Android to access SAMBA shares on Linux machines on my local network, but am hitting problems trying to generate the bridge with Java2OP.exe. Running:

```
java2op.exe -jar D:\Delphi\Android\Utils\slf4j-api-1.7.9.jar  -jar D:\Delphi\Android\Utils\bcprov-ext-debug-jdk15on-166.jar -jar D:\Delphi\Android\Utils\mbassador-1.3.2.jar -jar D:\Delphi\Android\Utils\asn-one-0.4.0.jar  -unit Androidapi.JNI.SambaJ
```

produces error:

```
eParsing jar: D:\Delphi\Android\Utils\bcprov-ext-debug-jdk15on-166.jar
Error: (Exception) - class or Interface expected
        > 1:1 "Warning: Binary file META-INF/versions/9/org/bouncycastle/jcajce/spec/DHDomainParameterSpec contains org.bouncycastle.jcajce.spec.DHDomainParameterSpec"
```

If I change the order thus:

```
java2op.exe -jar D:\Delphi\Android\Utils\slf4j-api-1.7.9.jar  -jar D:\Delphi\Android\Utils\mbassador-1.3.2.jar  -jar D:\Delphi\Android\Utils\bcprov-ext-debug-jdk15on-166.jar -jar D:\Delphi\Android\Utils\asn-one-0.4.0.jar  -unit Androidapi.JNI.SambaJ
```

I get the error message

```
Parsing jar: D:\Delphi\Android\Utils\mbassador-1.3.2.jar
Error: (Exception) - Generic Type "T" not defined
        > 221:63 "  public net.engio.mbassy.bus.SyncMessageBus$SyncPostCommand(T);"
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Error list:

```
Androidapi.JNI.SambaJ.pas issues: 
com.hierynomus.asn1.types.ASN1Object: not found 
com.hierynomus.asn1.types.constructed.ASN1TaggedObject: not found 
com.hierynomus.asn1.types.primitive.ASN1ObjectIdentifier: not found 
com.hierynomus.smbj.event.SMBEventBus$1: the parent class (net.engio.mbassy.bus.error.IPublicationErrorHandler) is not found 
com.hierynomus.smbj.transport.tcp.async.AsyncDirectTcpTransport$1: the parent class (java.nio.channels.CompletionHandler) is not found
```

Comment: Did you try processing just the main smbj.jar file? I don't think you need to create bridges for the dependencies. Just adding them to the Libraries entry in the Project Manager should be enough.

Comment: @Olivier: Thanks for suggestion, but "java2op.exe -jar D:\delphi\Android\Utils\smbj-0.10.0.jar -unit Androidapi.JNI.SambaJ" generates a long string of errors apparently relating to the dependencies. - TedB

Comment: Please post the errors (at least an excerpt).

Comment: @Olivier - thanks for your interest. Error list starts:Androidapi.JNI.SambaJ.pas issues:
 com.hierynomus.asn1.types.ASN1Object: not found
 com.hierynomus.asn1.types.constructed.ASN1TaggedObject: not found
 com.hierynomus.asn1.types.primitive.ASN1ObjectIdentifier: not found
 com.hierynomus.smbj.event.SMBEventBus$1: the parent class (net.engio.mbassy.bus.error.IPublicationErrorHandler) is not found
 com.hierynomus.smbj.transport.tcp.async.AsyncDirectTcpTransport$1: the parent class (java.nio.channels.CompletionHandler) is not found

Answer (score 2):

According to the [manual page](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Java2OP.exe,_the_Native_Bridge_File_Generator_for_Android), you should specify the jars as a space-separated list after the `-jar` option.

Moreover, since you're only interested in accessing SMBJ itself (not its dependencies), you should use the `-classes` option to specify the SMBJ packages you need.

Try something like this (paths omitted):

```
java2op -jar smbj-0.10.0.jar slf4j-api-1.7.9.jar bcprov-ext-debug-jdk15on-166.jar mbassador-1.3.2.jar asn-one-0.4.0.jar
  -classes com.hierynomus.smbj.* com.hierynomus.smbj.share.*
  -unit Androidapi.JNI.SambaJ
```

**EDIT**

Since there seems to be an issue with Java2OP and SMBJ, you can try [JCIFS](https://www.jcifs.org/) instead:

```
java2op -jar jcifs-1.3.19.jar -classes jcifs.smb.* -unit Androidapi.JNI.SambaJ
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Tried: "java2op.exe -jar D:\delphi\Android\Utils\smbj-0.10.0.jar D:\Delphi\Android\Utils\slf4j-api-1.7.9.jar D:\Delphi\Android\Utils\asn-one-0.4.0.jar  D:\Delphi\Android\Utils\mbassador-1.3.2.jar  D:\Delphi\Android\Utils\bcprov-ext-debug-jdk15on-166.jar -classes com.hierynomus.smbj.* com.hierynomus.smbj.share.*  -unit Androidapi.JNI.SambaJ", but still get the "Error: (Exception) - Generic Type "T" not defined
        > 221:63 "  public net.engio.mbassy.bus.SyncMessageBus$SyncPostCommand(T);" message

Comment: I'm afraid there is an issue with Java2OP :-(

Comment: I suggest you try [JCIFS](https://www.jcifs.org/) instead. It's even simpler, it has no dependency.

Comment: @ Olivier: Thanks for your help. There is an outstanding query on the Idera community forum regarding JCIFS, which your addition of the "classes" entry may resolve. It was that issue, plus reports of lack of JCIFS support for the latest SAMBA versions (???) that led me to try to try to use SMBJ instead. I will go back and try JCIFS again tomorrow.

Comment: @TedB On the JCIFS page, they mention [jcifs-codelibs](https://github.com/codelibs/jcifs) and [jcifs-ng](https://github.com/AgNO3/jcifs-ng), which support newer SMB versions. You may try them instead.

Comment: :(1) Ran "java2op.exe -jar D:\delphi\Android\Utils\jcifs-1.3.19.jar -classes jcifs.smb.* -unit Androidapi.JNI.Samba" which seemed to suceed.

(2) Added resulting ".pas" file to my project, and "Androidapi.JNI.Samba" to its user list.

(3) Tried to compile my project, and got 30 errors reported against Androidapi.JNI.Samba. These consisted of multiple instances of:

"function _Getthis$0: JNetServerEnum2Response; cdecl;"  - Reported error E2023 (Function needs result type)
"property this$0: JNetServerEnum2Response read _Getthis$0;" - Reported errors E2147,2029

Comment: 4) Downloaded jcifs-2.1.9.jar & ran "java2op.exe -jar D:\delphi\Android\Utils\jcifs-2.1.9.jar -classes jcifs.smb.* -unit Androidapi.JNI.Samba", & got the following errors:

Androidapi.JNI.Samba.pas issues:
 javax.security.auth.login.AppConfigurationEntry: not found
 javax.security.auth.login.Configuration: not found
 jcifs.smb.StaticJAASConfiguration: the parent class (javax.security.auth.login.Configuration) is not found
 org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1ObjectIdentifier: not found

but a bridge file was still produced.

Comment: (5) Trying to compile my project with this bridge file, the errors looked similar to those with JCIFS 1.3.19, but with different names ("function _Getval$token: TJavaArray<Byte>; cdecl;" & "property val$token: TJavaArray<Byte> read _Getval$token;"

(6) Tried jcifs-ng-2.1.5.jar, and appeared to get same results as jcifs-2.1.9.jar.